# Olympiad Function Question

Tags: functions, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

Does there exist a function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that for each $k= 0$, $1$, $\ldots$, $2016$ and for each $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ the equation $f(x) + kx = m$ has at least one solution $x\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes let $x_{k,m} \in \mathbb Z$ be different for each pair $(k,m)$ and define $f(x_{k,m}) = m - k x_{k,m}$. This would even work for all $k,m \in \mathbb Z$ since there exist one-to-one mappings from $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: How do you prove it holds for all k belonging to [0, 2016]

Comment: you just need the existence of a one-to-one map from $[0,2016] \times \mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$. For example $x_{k,m} = p_{m}^k$ where $p_m$ is the $m$-th prime (ok, it only works for $m \in \mathbb N$ but you can adapt for $m \in \mathbb Z$...)